Firebase build is passing but deploy is failing when deploying changes

Error: Assertion failed: resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name. This should have caused an error earlier

The firebasesrc is the right id ID and we have been making changes to the firebase.json but have not been able to get a passing pipeline.
We tried adding needs, dependencies, and cache to firebase.json. We also tried to re-initialize hosting. We are currently trying to deploy locally.
firebase.json:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}

